# Magento: import data from csv and get images with external url in Magento 1.7.0.0

Tags: magento-1.7

I am a beginner developer in Magento. I Import a CSV file having 20,000 products successfully in Magento 1.7.0.0. I have images in my CSV file with external URLs e.g. (http://mydomianname.xyz.net/images/ac123/image2/myimage.jpg)

After importing products I was unable to get images. When I check the path of image on my existing site that was:

```
http://exisitingdomianname/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/213x252/9df78eab45656d03d6e5sb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg
```

Please, any one can guide me how I can get images from any external url in magento.

Feel free to ask me if I am unable to explain my question properly.